# What is the difference between using TemplateView and ListView in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

In the database,  I have a set of questions. I want to display every question in a collapsible item as a list. Previously I used TemplateView:

```
class questionmanager(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'questionmanager.html'
    questions = Question.objects.all() 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = ({
            'questions': self.questions,
        })
        return context
```

Then, I read that using ListView is better practice to represent a list of objects. Then I changed my class to this:

```
class QuestionListView(ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

In the old template I used this for loop:

```
{% for question in questions %}
```

I thought I wouldn't need to use a for loop when I use ListView instead of TemplateView; but I couldn't list the items without a for loop. I found an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), and it seems to me, the only difference is that in the for loop we use **object_list** ( `{% for question in **object_list** %}`) instead of using argument that we pass in the context.

I really don't see so much difference between using TemplateView and ListView - after spending an hour on this. I'd appreciate if someone explains why using ListView instead of TemplateView is a better practice (in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For simple use cases such as this, there isn't much difference. However, the `ListView` in this example is much cleaner as it can be reduced to:

```
class QuestionListView(ListView):
    model = Question
```

considering you aren't putting anything in the context. `TemplateView's` as a base view are rather rudimentary, and provide a much smaller set of methods and attributes to work with for the more complex use cases, meaning you have to write more code in such instances. If you take a look and compare both views [TemplateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) and [ListView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) here, you can see the difference more clearly. Pagination is a good example, to paginate a `ListView` you simply set the `paginate_by` attribute and modify your template accordingly.

Also note, you can change the default name `object_list` by setting `context_object_name` in the 'ListView'

Comment: Thank you. The Hierarchy diagrams in the links you gave are very useful. I also found out I can change the default name by overriding the get_context_object_name function. I think understanding difference clearly will take time and experience. But if you can provide a good example of using ListView, that'd be great. Thanks again!

Comment: The example you gave is a textbook case for using a `ListView`, even though you could use a `TemplateView` instead, there really is no reason to in this case. With most of the generic class-based views you'll find that you can make them to work like other class-based views, but there really isn't any sense in doing so for the typical use case.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is that ListView is best to list items from a database called model, while TemplateView is best to render a template with no model. Both views can be very concise with different meaning.
Below is sample of a list view in it simplest form

```
Class SampleListView(ListView):
    model = ModelName
```

This will give you a context variable object_list and a template name in the form ("app_name/model_name_list.html") automatically that can be used to list all records in the database.

However, the TemplateView in its simplest form is

```
class SampleTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_name/filename.html'
```